# how to get a real null value instead of a JSONObject.NULL value when parsing JSON in grails

Tags: json, grails, groovy, null

I'm trying to parse some JSON in Grails using the grails.converters.JSON library.  I have a field which will contain either a string, or a null value.  When I parse the JSON and get the field, the null values come back as a JSONObject.NULL type.  This is not good when checking != null as JSONObject.NULL is evaluated as non-null (not good for null checks)

```
def obj = JSON.parse('{"date1":null,"date2":"2011-06-26T05:00:00Z"}')
def date1 = obj.date1
if (date1)
     parse(date1)   // parse error occurs here because date1 evaluates true in the if because it is JSONObject.NULL
```

Is there an easy way to get the parse to parse a real null value so that I don't have to check if the object is a JSONObject.NULL.

I tried the suggestion [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/JSON-Converter-td1319688.html) to use .toString(), but it ended up returning the string value 'null' instead of actual null for a JSONObject.NULL value.

Comment: there is the closing quote missing for the date string. is this maybe the issue?

Comment: this is example code for illustration, not actual running code.  it's for illustration.  I've corrected the quote, but that's not the problem I'm illustrating

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/The-groovy-truth-of-JSONObject-Null-td3661040.html

Ian Roberts mentions a nice trick to make a null check possible:

```
JSONObject.NULL.metaClass.asBoolean = {-> false}
```

Comment: Note that this still does not allow you to use the safe navigation operator `?.` as would be natural with a "real" map.

Answer (score 19):

You may find this more useful and natural

```
    JSONObject.NULL.equals(jsonObj.get("key_name"))
```

Comment: I am getting `NullPointerException` when I use `JSONObject.NULL.equals(...)`. In the debugger I see that `JSONObject.NULL = null`....

Comment: Depending on the library you are using, please see
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.html#NULL
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#NULL

Answer (score -2):

I think I found a better solution, which consists in overriding the `toString()` method implementation of the `JSONObject.NULL` inner class by copying the `JSONObject.java` file into your Grails `src/java` project and then changing the implementation to this:

```
    /**
     * Get the "" string value.
     * @return An empty String "".
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
```

Once you restart with this new class in your classpath, the classloader will use your `JSONObject` class instead of the one packaged in the Grails dependencies.

Make sure you keep it in the same package as the original.

For more details you can go here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9129

Hope it helps :-)