# How to tell Grails to render JSONNull as null?

Tags: json, grails, null, grails-2.0.4

I have a JSON object returned from Groovy's HTTPBuilder. THE JSON contains some null values represented as JSONNull objects. The problem is that when I try to render the JSON back in a response, I get an error when it tries to render the JSONNull. I get a response that is only partially rendered. I want it to render as "null". How do I do this?

**Code:**

```
render(contentType: "text/json") {
    listOfJSONObjectsThatIncludeJSONNulls
}
```

**Error:**

```
| Error 2013-09-17 11:33:56,965 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - JSONException occurred when processing request: [GET] /my/action
Object is null. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Object is null
   Line | Method
->>  69 | isEmpty        in net.sf.json.JSONNull
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   199 | value          in grails.converters.JSON
|   162 | convertAnother in     ''
|   199 | value          in     ''
|   162 | convertAnother in     ''
|   199 | value          in     ''
|   162 | convertAnother in     ''
|   199 | value          in     ''
|   162 | convertAnother in     ''
|   199 | value          in     ''
|   162 | convertAnother in     ''
|   199 | value          in     ''
|   162 | convertAnother in     ''
|   199 | value          in     ''
|   134 | render . . . . in     ''
|   150 | render         in     ''
|    63 | doCall . . . . in myproject.MyController$_index_closure1_closure2_closure4$$EOHirVeS
|   477 | doRequest      in groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
|   417 | doRequest . .  in     ''
|   349 | request        in     ''
|    43 | doCall . . . . in myproject.MyController$_index_closure1$$EOHirVeS
|   477 | doRequest      in groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
|   268 | get . . . . .  in     ''
|    31 | index          in myproject.MyController$$EOHirVeS
|   895 | runTask . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run            in     ''
^   680 | run . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

**Partially Rendered Output:**

```
[{"keyWithNullValue":{"array":false,"class":"net.sf.json.JSONNull"
```

Comment: Don't you hate it when someone asks a question and no feedback how he solved the issue or if the solutions provided where right...

Comment: @Armand Sorry. I checked my code and found what I ended up doing. I added an answer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the following code to render JSONNull as an empty string.

```java
grails.converters.JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(JSONNull, { return "" })
```

Comment: I came across the exact problem today, and thanks to this answer, was able to solve it really quickly.

A question I have is: Where do you register the object marshaller as above: just before you render the JSON? Does it have to be done for every method that does so if you expect JSONNulls in the response?

Comment: @ashes, I put it in the controller before the response. But, I imagine you could put it someplace more central, I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix it by specifying the below one in BootStrap

```
JSONObject.NULL.metaClass.asBoolean = {-> false}
```

Have a look at: [how to get a real null value instead of a JSONObject.NULL value when parsing JSON in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860781/how-to-get-a-real-null-value-instead-of-a-jsonobject-null-value-when-parsing-jso)